# Deprecated: Function get_magic_quotes_gpc() is deprecated in WordPress that causes height change in hoe slider, all Tabs on website

Tags: warnings

I am looking for effect of this warning on your website

> Deprecated: Function get_magic_quotes_gpc() is deprecated in WordPress

- after this warning change in my website home slider height
- change in height of every tab of website

Comment: Is Hoe Slider a 3rd party plugin? Thee only place in WordPress that uses `get_magic_quotes_gpc` is a check that returns  an error message in the ID3 library very early on, it would not cause frontend layout issues. Locate the plugin/theme that is using `get_magic_quotes_gpc` and either modify it, remove it, or report to the vendor

Comment: What's a hoe slider?

Answer (score 1):

magic_quotes_gpc is a php.ini setting to automatically add backslash escapes to certain characters in input values (from GPC = Get, Post, Cookie). It's been long deprecated in PHP, back as far as 5.x I think.

I guess either your theme or a slider plugin is calling this because WordPress core doesn't (except one reference in the included ID3). I can't imagine why the functionality would break your layout, so I guess it's the printing the warning that is.

The best solution is to work out whether the warning is coming from your theme or a plugin - it should be obvious from the file and line number printed - and contact the author of that for an update. However if you want to fix this yourself, I'd

- double-check that you don't have `magic_quotes_gpc = on` in your php.ini file, i.e. that you aren't actually using it (although I don't think it works anymore anyway)
- replace the calls to `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` in the relevant code with just 0, which has been the default in many PHP versions now.